# Within Perl, how can I mark a generated file as executeable?

Tags: perl, file, executable

In my perl script, I create a shell script (something to post-process the results of a long simulation).  I'd like to mark this file as executable.

```
$fileName = 'postProcess.tcsh';
```

Clearly, I could do the following:

```
system("chmod +x $fileName");
```

But I'm curious if there is a solution which avoids the system call. In other words, would there be a method within the File module perhaps?  What say you monks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Perl's builtin [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) function:

```
chmod 0755, $fileName;
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you find yourself calling system() to do a file-related operation, chances are good that Perl has a built-in function that you should use instead.  (The Perl function name will usually match the C function name, not the command-line tool name (e.g., open()/utime() instead of "touch") so don't give up if you don't find it right away.)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the mode when first creating the file.

```
use Fcntl;
sysopen my $fh, $filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0777;
# instead of
#open my $fh, '>', $filename;
```

The `0777` mode will be `&` with your current `umask`.